# Where is the best place to make API calls in a react/redux/reach router application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I'm struggling to understand where the best place to make API calls in my app is?

I have my main component like this:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <Provider store={store}>
            <Router />
        </Provider>
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById('root'),
)
```

and inside `Router` I have all my routes. some of my other pages require making API calls to a server to get information so im wondering where the best place/best design would be to put these?

I have a component called `PageOne` and in there I make an API call on mount to retrieve some data and then add it to my redux state. but I also need the same data in my `PageTwo` component. obviously if the user goes via `PageOne` > `PageTwo` this is fine because that data is in the redux store so I just grab it. but im wondering if they went directly to `PageTwo` or refreshed the page whilst on `PageTwo`. that data would no longer be fetched.

so my options feel like:

1. fetch the data again on `PageTwo`. but this seems like I could be making a lot of requests (plus unnecessary requests as I might be fetching when I already have it)
2. can I put the fetch inside the router component? I guess this would always trigger no matter what page I went too. but again I would be doing unnecessary requests potentially

is there any "good"/best practice way of handling this?

Comment: Have you tried reading some React data fetching tutorials? There are a lot of resources out there. "react data fetching patterns" "react data fetching best practices" "react data fetching"

Comment: Something else you might want to look into is caching, or even throttling. That can help you manage redundant fetches.

Comment: @Cully ok thanks I'll take a look. I know how to do it of course, I'm more trying to optimise it. when you say caching, you mean storing in like browser session state/storage for example?

Comment: What I mean is essentially [memoizing](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/understanding-memoize-in-javascript-51d07d19430e/) your requests for a certain amount of time (e.g. 1 second, 60 seconds, 10 minutes, or just while the request is being made). That way if multiple requests are made to the same endpoint, you don't actually need to make a network request to fulfill each one. You probably don't need to worry about caching between page refreshes (i.e. local storage). Search for "react caching requests".

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your data fetching logic inside the redux action where you need to just call the same dispatch action whenever you want to fetch the data.

Like this:

```
return async dispatch => {
       const res = await axios.post(`${rootUrl}/login`, data);
              localStorage.setItem("authToken", 

    JSON.stringify(res.data.authToken));
                  // Set token
                  // setTokenToAxios(res.data.authToken);
                  dispatch({
                    type: USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS,
                    data: res.data.authToken
                  });
    };
```

You can dispatch or invoke the action in componentDidMount or useEffect() whatever you use in.

You can put invoke or dispatch the action in both components with a flag to avoid unnecessary data fetching.